# Can this interesting property be proven?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$2^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+9^2+11^2=(17)^2$$
$$22^2+33^2+55^2+77^2+99^2+11^2=(143)^2$$

Also:

$$22^2+33^2+55^2+77^2+99^2+121^2=(187)^2$$
$$222^2+333^2+555^2+777^2+999^2+1221^2=(1887)^2$$
$$2222^2+3333^2+5555^2+7777^2+9999^2+12221^2=(18887)^2$$
$$22222^2+33333^2+55555^2+77777^2+99999^2+122221^2=(188887)^2$$

How can I prove this?

Are there other interesting properties like these?

Comment: Note, the second on has a simpler starting point: $2^2+3^3+5^2+7^2+9^2+1^2=13^2$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hint: What happens if you multiply your first identity with $111\cdots1^2$?

Comment: And the same thing can be done to $1^2+2^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+9^2=13^2$ which is implicit in the second identity.

Comment: $11\cdots111$ is a good multiplier, because multiplying small (most notably single digit) numbers with it doesn't lead to any carries. And that makes the resulting sequences look more convincing.